# Dealing with a preceding comma when parsing JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm querying an API for some JSON formatted data but it is coming back with slightly invalid formatting. There is a preceding comma which is causing a problem, I was wondering if there was any way around this?

I'm using the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library to issue the API queries and read the JSON like so:

```
resp = requests.get(citedByURL % (eid, apiKey, citedByPerPage, startPoint))
data = resp.json()
```

The JSON has an error which you can see here:

```
"entry": [{, "link": [{"@ref": "self", "@href": "http://api.elsevier.com/content/abstract/scopus_id/77957867010"}
```

And hence Python throws the following error:

```
ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 1164 (char 1163)
```

Is there anything I can do to maybe preprocess the data before attempting to load it as JSON?

Comment: What other variations are possible?

Comment: You should fix the server code that's sending invalid JSON.

Comment: I would if I could, it's a third party API that I'm querying, I've sent the development team an email but was wondering if there was anything I could do in the mean time

Comment: Padraic I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean can the comma appear anywhere and is it only a stray comma that can possibly be misplaced? i.e would `json.loads(re.sub("{(\s+)?,","{",r.content))` fix the issue

Comment: It seems like the stray commas in that particular place is the only issue. That does fix the issue for now actually thank you, it's not ideal hopefully the developers will fix the issue soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resp = requests.get(citedByURL % (eid, apiKey, citedByPerPage, startPoint))
data = resp.text()
data = data.replace("[{,", "[{")
data = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: That will remove more than just the comma.

Comment: I've added the preceding line for clarification, I'm using the Python response library. Is there any way to make that edit to the content before attempting to load it as JSON?